# show div or content by clicking next and prev till fixed stage using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".pr-calendar div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
       $(this).hide();
  });

  $("#next").click(function(){
    if ($(".pr-calendar div:visible").next().length != 0)
       $(".pr-calendar div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
       $(".pr-calendar div:visible").hide();
       $(".pr-calendar div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".pr-calendar div:visible").prev().length != 0)
       $(".pr-calendar div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
       $(".pr-calendar div:visible").hide();
       $(".pr-calendar div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.f-d{
  background-color: #01BC8C;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1px;
}
.pr-calendar{
  background-color: #01BC8C;
}
.see-upline{
  background-color: #F89A15;
}
.lt-news{
  background-color: #428BCA;
}
.upline-chart{
  background-color: #EF706D;
}
.myprofit-calendar{
  background: #CCC;
  position: relative;
}
.prev-next-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#prev { left: 10px; }
#next { right: 10px; }
.pr-calendar table{
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
.pr-calendar table td{
  padding: 5px;
  color:#fff;
}

.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
  <div class="col-lg-3 margin_10 animated fadeInRightBig">
    <div class="myprofit-calendar">
      <div class="f-d pr-calendar">
        <div class="month">
          <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->                                     
          <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">July 2017</h3>
          <table class="table-responsive">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="warning">
                <td>SEO</td>
                <td>8%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>Affiliate</td>
                <td>10%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>Webs</td>
                <td>12%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="warning">
                <td>Apps</td>
                <td>15%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                <td>20%</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="month">
          <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->                                        
          <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">August 2017</h3>
          <table class="table-responsive">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="warning">
                <td>SEO</td>
                <td>5%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>Affiliate</td>
                <td>15%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>Webs</td>
                <td>9%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="warning">
                <td>Apps</td>
                <td>17%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                <td>15%</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="month">
          <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->                                        
          <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">September 2017</h3>
          <table class="table-responsive">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="warning">
                <td>SEO</td>
                <td>2%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="danger">
                <td>Affiliate</td>
                <td>5%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>Webs</td>
                <td>15%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="warning">
                <td>Apps</td>
                <td>10%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="info">
                <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                <td>11%</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a id="next" class="prev-next-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
      <a id="prev" class="prev-next-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set july month div to show by default and after clicking next will show the august month max.But, when clicked prev button , I want to show to previous 11 months till september .In, other words, I want to make a profit calendar, which will show the profit percentage month wise that will start from july till jun , july is the beginning point. What code should I write, please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of different solutions for your problem.

I can suggest to use:

```
$(".pr-calendar div:visible").index()
```

The previous line will return the index of the month div in the set.

Another possibility is to test the content in the children h3 element.

A snippet based on the last idea is:

```js
$(".pr-calendar div").each(function (idx, ele) {
    $(this).toggle($(this).children('h3').text().toLowerCase().indexOf('july') != -1);
});

$("#next").click(function () {
    if ($(".pr-calendar div:visible h3").text().toLowerCase().indexOf('august') == -1)
        $(".pr-calendar div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".pr-calendar div:visible").hide();
        $(".pr-calendar div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    if ($(".pr-calendar div:visible h3").text().toLowerCase().indexOf('september') != -1) {
        $(".pr-calendar div:visible").nextAll('div:eq(10)').show().end().hide();
        return false;
    }
    if ($(".pr-calendar div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".pr-calendar div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
        $(".pr-calendar div:visible").hide();
        $(".pr-calendar div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

```css
.f-d {
    background-color: #01BC8C;
    height: 220px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.pr-calendar {
    background-color: #01BC8C;
}

.see-upline {
    background-color: #F89A15;
}

.lt-news {
    background-color: #428BCA;
}

.upline-chart {
    background-color: #EF706D;
}

.myprofit-calendar {
    background: #CCC;
    position: relative;
}

.prev-next-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#prev {
    left: 10px;
}

#next {
    right: 10px;
}

.pr-calendar table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.pr-calendar table td {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
    <div class="col-lg-3 margin_10 animated fadeInRightBig">
        <div class="myprofit-calendar">
            <div class="f-d pr-calendar">

                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">September 2016</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">October 2016</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">November 2016</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">December 2016</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">January 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">February 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">March 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">April 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">May 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">June 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">July 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>8%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>12%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>20%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">August 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>5%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>9%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>17%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <!--   <i class="livicon" data-name="calendar" data-size="50" data-c="#fff" data-hc="#fff" data-loop="true"></i>-->
                    <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #fff;">September 2017</h3>
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>SEO</td>
                            <td>2%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="danger">
                            <td>Affiliate</td>
                            <td>5%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Webs</td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="warning">
                            <td>Apps</td>
                            <td>10%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Crypto&Mining</td>
                            <td>11%</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>


            </div>
            <a id="next" class="prev-next-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
            <a id="prev" class="prev-next-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```